# Full Text Search in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, search, full-text-search

I am working on the Full Text Search in Sql Server 2005. I have created a catalog and then an index on a particular table.

I am searching for data using FREETEXTTABLE(tablename,*,@SearchKeyword). So I am searching in all columns in the index since any of the columns can contain the keywords.

Is there is a way for me to know which columns in the index contained my search keywords?(without having to go and look at each column in the resultset)?

I would appreciate any help in this regard. Thanks.

Kalyan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you'd have to query each column individually.

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for the reply. As you mentioned I can query each column and find out if it contains the keywords that I am searching for, But I also need to show some sample text from the column that contains the keywords,so how do i know where in the column the keywords were found? Is the keyword present in the first 50 characters or 100 characters..? I would appreciate any suggestions.Thanks.

Comment: If you were running SQL 2008, you might be able to leverage [sys.dm_fts_index_keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280900.aspx) to answer the "which column" question. As for displaying the sample text, I'm not aware of a way to do this using just SQL Server. This need is probably better served by writing some application code instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help joe,I will try to take that approach and see how it works out.